# Network device naming problems and aliases for p2p1 and p3p1 back to eth0 and eth1

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet, network-interface

I'm having a heck of a time getting the networking stack up and running on a Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 installation. (Its personal for the house and I'm not a SA, so I can't ask on SF because its a violation of the site's policies).

The problem is the network device names and inconsistency through the kernel and applications. Its apparently a well known problem once you encounter it and know what to search for. (Cf., [Consistent Network Device Naming in Linux](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf) and [Ethernet names not consistent ubuntu server 14.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220120)).

The machine has a pair of onboard NICs on the PCI Express bus. They are Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller. In ***`dmesg`***, I see the Realtek driver performs a rename:

- eth0 → p2p1
- eth1 → p3p1

When the driver performs the rename, it breaks a lot of stuff, like things in ***`/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`*** and ***`/etc/network/interfaces`***. The later is especially problematic because I already have libvirt installed and a few VMs partially configured in bridged mode.

In an effort to [minimize trouble and avoid extra work](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf), I'd like to allow the driver to perform the rename, but provide an alias that parts of the kernel and applications expect.

How do I create an alias such that:

- eth0 is an alias for p2p1
- eth1 is an alias for p3p1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do't get it. If the driver consistently renames everything to `p2p1` and `p3p1`, why don't you uniformly use `p2p1` and `p3p1` everywhere?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae - I'm happy to use `p2p1` and friends. But some stuff that comes with the server expects the old name. I don't know why server components, like some of its scripts, require the old names. Maybe I should file a bug against Ubuntu for it...