# How to convert /etc/interfaces settings into udev rules?

Tags: linux, networking, udev

I'm trying to set up a bridged networking interface for kvm/libvirt. I'm having trouble doing so because the tutorials are written for non-udev systems using configuration files like `/etc/interfaces`. However, recent OSes, like Debian 8 and Ubuntu 14, use udev. Following the tutorials and adding configuration information to the older conf files just breaks networking.

How do I convert configuration files into udev rules? Is there a Linux utility to do it? Or is there something else to use for it?

---

Related information includes [Consistent Network Device Naming in Linux](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf). It explains why some systems abandon ***`eth0`*** and friends specified in `/etc/interfaces`, why some systems use ***`p2p1`*** and friends, and why they show up in udev rules.

Comment: No kernel _ever_ has used `/etc/interfaces` (network config would be a distro/userspace thing anyway), udev rules are _not_ a replacement for network configuration, and there weren't any major network configuration changes in 3.x – it was an arbitrary version bump with more or less identical features as 2.6.x. As it is, the question is just nonsensical.

Comment: @grawity - I can say for certain the problems with udev are real. What component do you think assigns names like ***`p2p1`*** and ***`p2p2`***? Its incompatible with classic settings in configuration files, like `/etc/interfaces`. Also see [Network device naming problems and aliases for p2p1 and p3p1 back to eth0 and eth1](http://superuser.com/q/1017199).

Comment: More nonsense. If udev renames a network interface, that doesn't mean it's automatically responsible for configuring everything else. And, assuming you mean Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces`, there is no place where "classic settings in configuration files" require that names would start with `eth`; I've personally used it for interfaces named `eno2`, `enp3s1`, `lan1`, `gre-dn42`...

Comment: @grawity - the only nonsense are your comments. udev is the kernel's device manager, whether you agree with it or not. The kernel or udev does ***not*** honor *`/etc/interfaces`*. I've got a [Qotom T5200U](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016RWCC2I) with dual NICs sitting in front of me that tells me so, whether you agree with it or not.

Comment: I know exactly what udev does. Even though in v209 it gained the ability to configure network interfaces at a low level (things like MTU, duplex, etc.) via .link files, it still doesn't replace `/etc/interfaces` in any way. It won't set up a bridge for you. (Unless maybe you're mixing it up with `systemd-networkd`, which *does* set up bridging and other high-level features via .netdev files.)

Answer (score 2):

`udev` triggers things when hardware add-remove type events are detected.  it doesn't have anything to do with network activity AFAIK.

I'm not too keen on the precise operation of `udev` but besides choosing the name of a device based on some attribute and a couple other actions, I think anything else you want done would have to be a script triggered by `udev`.

`udev` also is not involved when interfaces come up or down, just when they are physically added and removed from the system.

So you might as well follow the standard and use `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Bridging involves creating a bridge and adding interfaces to it.  The bridge is not a real device and I don't think `udev` has a chance to trigger anything.  Same with `tap` and `tun` interfaces.

`udev` is useful for this purpose only with network interfaces: you can create `udev` rules to assign names to your real NICs, typically based on MAC address.  Afterward those names can be specified in `/etc/network/interfaces`.